# What is the difference between async.each and async.forEach?

Tags: node.js, async.js

How are `async.each` and `async.forEach` different? Are there any performance differences?

Comment: They are identical (aliases) see the documentation (http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)

Comment: oh...I had seen the methods area and I couldn't find forEach so I assumed the documentation is not complete. Can you write your comment as an answer. I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async.each` and `async.forEach` are aliases of each other (see https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each).

As of today, you can now find the aliased methods in the search bar (https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/1339). If you're interested you can also vote on https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/1340 which would add the aliases to the TOC